# JAXB / XJC - generate a class from XS:Group

Tags: xml, jaxb, xjc

I'm using JAXB for the first time and have some really bad XML that I can't change that I would like to generate classes for.

The XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
   <contacts>
      <name>...</name>
      <phone>...</phone>
      <address>..</address>
      <name>...</name>
      <phone>...</phone>
      <address>..</address>
      <name>...</name>
      <phone>...</phone>
      <address>..</address>
  </contacts>
</root>
```

So I thought ok, maybe I can refer to the contacts element as a sequence of groups.  Relevant parts:

```
<xs:group name="Contact">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xs:element name="phone" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="ContactList">
    <xs:sequence><xs:group maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Contact"/></xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, my ContactList object just has a getter that looks like:

`public List<JAXBElement<?>> getContact()`

Why is a Contact object not declared, and how can I fix this?  I don't think I can declare Contact as a complex type since it's not contained in an element.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to start by transforming the bad XML into good XML using XSLT. It will then be much easier to process the data in Java. (Who knows, perhaps you can handle the data entirely in XSLT and avoid converting it to Java format entirely.) Without a decent structure to play with, the Java mapping can be pretty awful.

Comment: +1 - JAXB integrates very well with XSLT via the `javax.xml.transform` APIs:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html